# Displaying directory content is extremely slow

Tags: windows-10

Why does it take half a minute to list my files in Windows 10 file explorer?

[image]

Comment: Your drive may be corrupt or there may be a process eating up all the disk bandwidth. Check in Process Monitor and sort by disk usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disable the realtime protection](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3569-turn-off-windows-defender-real-time-protection-windows-10-a.html) of [windows defender, it scans files in download folder](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/case-of-the-slow-downloads-folder/) and causes the delay from time to time.

Comment: Your downloads folder is probably one of the most important things to protect, please don't advise people to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing was the problem for me.

Some suggest diabling the indexer completely, whereas I have had luck with the following:

Right click on the folder, Properties ⇒ Attributes ⇒ Advanced

Uncheck "Allow files in this folder to have contentes indexed in addition to file properties", and apply recursively.